# how to retrieve the sum of column values in simplecursoradapter in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Am using db query to sum the column values by using group by clause. I can get the total amount but i couldn't display the values in simplecursoradapter. Please help me to display the total values. I have posted my code below.

```
String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_CATEGORY,"sum("+KEY_AMOUNT+")as" + KEY_AMOUNT,
            KEY_COMMENT };
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLENAME2, columns, null, null, null, null,
            null);
    return cursor;
```

To display the values in Listview using Simplecursoradapter

```
String[] from = new String[] { Dailydialog.KEY_CATEGORY,
                Dailydialog.KEY_AMOUNT,Dailydialog.KEY_COMMENT};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.id2, R.id.id3,R.id.id4};
        cursorAdapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.dailydialogall, cursor1,
                from, to);
        listview_dialog.setAdapter(cursorAdapter1);
```

Total values are not listed in Listview.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `"sum("+KEY_AMOUNT+")as" + KEY_AMOUNT` use `" sum("+KEY_AMOUNT+") as " + KEY_AMOUNT`. Notice the spaces? Its always a good idea to print your query in log. Another thing is that you need to specify `group by` clause as well for sum function otherwise only one row will be returned with total sum of amount of all the rows.

Comment: ya i have changed my query with space n used group by but stil am not getting.it is possible to get the result in the String[] i have mentioned in my second set of codes.?